# Can <?=$var?> syntax cause problems?

Tags: php

I know the syntax for `<? ?>` is not always allowed, and will spark notices if you have them enabled... but I haven't seen many people use `<?=$var?>` to echo a variable... is this illegal syntax or completely accepted in all versions of PHP?

```
<?php echo $var; ?>
```

vs

```
<?=$var?>
```

Comment: depends if it has been enabled on the server on which you are running the code.

Comment: It was disabled for some PHP versions, but has now been reinstated - so it isn't guaranteed

Comment: @Maximus2012 so it does have to be enabled? It is not standard?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Comment: [This answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php) might have some insight.

Comment: @ChrisRasco Thanks for the link, I just flagged my question as duplicate of the link you posted.

Comment: @AmalMurali I'd rather just close it and have it point to short tags link... I personally thought <?= was different than short tags <? So this will help the next person that searches just for it <?=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it depends on your **php.ini** settings. `short_open_tag` has to be `On`.

Your code will not work, if short open tags aren't allowed (old servers [< PHP 5.4.0] often don't support it by default). If you'd like to write your code **downwards compatible**, do not use it.

I got a lot of anoying trouble because of being lazy and using short open tags. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Before PHP 5.4.0, this syntax required the [`short_open_tag`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) flag to be enabled.  Since 5.4.0, it's always usable.